# Running windows command prompt commands in a Qt application

Tags: c++, windows, qt, command-line

I need to run an external exe through Qt application which requires commands to be entered in windows command prompt.

```
  QString exePath = "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe";
  QProcess pro;
  pro.start(exePath);
  pro.execute("cmd.exe");
```

But I got output like below [plain cmd prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TK9Zl.png)

But I want windows command prompt like [expected cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Jmw.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to read from QProcess standart output and print it on screen.
You can use `pro.waitForReadyRead()` and if it returns true do

```
QByteArray arr = pro.readAllStandardOutput();
QString str(arr);
qDebug() << str;
```

Better decision is to use signal slot mechanism and implement `onReadyToRead()` slot and connect QProcess `readyReadStandardOutput()` signal to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
pro.start(exePath);
pro.execute("cmd.exe");
```

You should not use this two methods at same time, QProcess::execute is static member.

You need to start process detached:

```
QString exePath = "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe";
QProcess pro;
pro.startDetached(exePath);
pro.waitForStarted();
//Event Loop here
```