# Exchange data between Qt Application and nodejs server

Tags: node.js, qt, stdout, stdin, qprocess

I have created a web server architecture in nodejs which serves web pages when running. 
On the other hand I have a Qt GUI application.
I need to make an interface between these two.
I have already created the connection between these two using QProcess (the server now starts from this Qt application)
Now I want to exchange some data between them, for example a random message on the web page from GUI and back.
Is stdin/out of any use here?
Can you please guide me through this? Here is my server code:

```
 `function init() {

var __website = path.join(__dirname, 'Website/');
var __css = path.join(__dirname, 'css/');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__website)));
app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index', function (err, html) {
        res.send(html);
    });
});
app.get('/data/:iValue', function( req, res) {
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk != null) {
    res.json({response: chunk.toString("UTF-8")});
     }
 });
   process.stdout.write('request_data:' + temperature);

});
}
function initSocket() {
var Session = require('express-session');
var MemoryStore = require('session-memory-store')(Session);
var session = new Session({
 store: new MemoryStore(),
 secret: 'supersecret',
 resave: true,
 saveUninitialized: true
})

//io = require('socket.io')(https);
io = new ioServer();
io.use(ios(session));
// In-memory storage
// Begin listening for a websockets connection
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('setRange', data.min, data.max);
    socket.emit('setEmails', data.emails);
    setInterval(function () {
    var temperature;
        //var temperature = Math.floor((Math.random() * 20) + 15);
        socket.emit('updateTemperature', {
            temperature: temperature
        });
        if (temperature < data.min || temperature > data.max) {
            // console.log('alert! ' + temperature + ' min:' + data.min + ' 
max:' + data.max)
            sendEmail(temperature);
            socket.emit('alert', {
                temperature: temperature,
                message: 'Temp is outside of Value Range'
            });
        }
    }, 2000);`
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your problem

Comment: Try to use [qwebsocket](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebsocket.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `QProcess` can grip `stdout`, `stderr`. you can listen to its output with [readyReadStandardOutput](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardOutput) signal emitted by the process then read by any of qprocess read methods like [readAllStandardOutput()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#readyReadStandardOutput).. also you can have your gui send messages to nodejs standard input with [`QIODevice::write(const char *data)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#write) inherited function.

Comment: Look at this example to get started [QProcess example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069807/passing-giving-commands-to-cmd-through-qt-gui/49074579#49074579), the thing is nodejs, be able to read or write back to std outpout/err.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will work on it further this way!

Comment: Hello Mr. @Mohammad Kanan, I have tried using these functions in my application
  the application now returns an error in the debug. Now I think I have to make some changes in my server.js where I need to recieve/snd data

Comment: Yes, you need server.js to write to stdout. also please don't put code in comments, its not easily readable.

Comment: for example;my qt application shows a random value every second with variable name "itemp" and I need to send this value to my webpage with id "Act_temp" (at the moment "Act_temp" receives a Math.random value from server.js. For this, what & where exactly should I change my code?

Comment: In a layman's term, iI should replace math.random function with "itemp". right? but how to do it? I mean what is the process of replacing this? @Mohammad Kanan

Comment: Depends what your server structures can accept, you could try `json` array or text stream, use `QProess::write`

Comment: you mean to send "itemp" from Qt program, I should use QProcess:: write? but you can't tell how server.js would receive it in place of Math.random ?

Comment: You need to try [process.stdin](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_stdin)

Comment: Hey, thank you. So far, when I used  myProcess->write("data_from_qt:" + itemp);
 I am getting the actual temperature value from qt application into my application output. next step is to make server.js receive this itemp value, you suggested stdin, I am not yet clear how to modify the code(on the link process.stdin) to my requirement. How would server.js know that it has to recive itemp value from qt application. I mean does it need for example something in header?

Comment: AFAIK, `stdin` can't be interpreted in a predefined way, its just a byte ararry, you need to capture it and qualify to the parameter you want, for example by a reg exp .. or string methods.

Comment: I have used stdin as you suggested, but I am still not receiving the value on my web page. Please refer to the code in my question. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have to make the server be a child process of the GUI program and vise versa.

You need some IPC([Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication))mechanism here, such as [`shared memory`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) or [`named pipe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).

And the `Socket`  which is usually for network programming  can be used to make two processes communicatable too.

(I just found that `node.js` doesn't have `FIFO(named pipe)` or `shared memory` packages. So, It seems that the only way you can achieve your demand is using `Socket`.)